# Bounds or approximation on $\frac{1-\mathrm{erf}(x)}{1+\mathrm{erf}(x)}$

Tags: error-function

Any ideas how I can obtain a tight lower, upper bound, or approximation on

$$f(x)=\frac{1-\mathrm{erf}(x)}{1+\mathrm{erf}(x)}$$
for almost any $x$.

This function $f(x)$ grows as $e^{x^2}$ on $x\ll 0$ and decays as $e^{-x^2}$ on $x\gg 0$. I need a tight lower, upper bound, or approximation that captures both the exponential growth for $x<0$ and the exponential decay for $x>0$.
Thank you for you efforts!

Comment: Does something like $e^{-\mathrm{sgn}(x)x^2}$ meet your requirements? See [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)

Comment: Please look at [this post](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/norm-dist-bounds/) on John D. Cook's blog.

Comment: Write it as $$
2 - \frac{1}{{2 - \operatorname{erfc}(x)}}
$$ and use http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.12.i

Answer (score 0):

In terms of approximation, instead of looking at
$$f(x)=\frac{1-\text{erf}(x)}{1+\text{erf}(x)}$$ it could probably be better to consider
$$g(x)=\log \left(\frac{1-\text{erf}(x)}{1+\text{erf}(x)}\right)$$
Expanded as series around $x=0$
$$g(x)=-\frac{4 x}{\sqrt{\pi }}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\, x^{2n}$$ Even if all coefficients are known, the series solution or its corresponding $[2n+1,2n]$ Padé approximants are acceptable for a limited range $(|x]< \pi)$.

So, the best I could do is a curve fit by a rational approximation
$$g(x)=-\frac{4 x}{\sqrt{\pi }}\, \frac {1+\sum_{n=1}^p b_n\, x^{2n} }{1+\sum_{n=1}^p c_n\, x^{2n}  }$$

Generating the data for $0 \leq x \leq 10$, using $p=3$, the regression leads to $R^2=0.999999967$ and the rationalized coefficients are
$$b_1=\frac{3235}{2114} \qquad \qquad b_2= \frac{806}{3745}\qquad \qquad b_3=\frac{1}{357} $$
$$c_1=\frac{3307}{2291} \qquad \qquad c_2= \frac{309}{4049}\qquad \qquad c_3=\frac{1}{4885} $$